# How can I get rid of these points around the hips of my model when using the subdivision modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, armature, edit-mode, sculpting

I am trying to model this character but the hips keep pointing out of the model... How can I make it more uniform with the body?

[image: Pointy Hips]

[image: Pointy Hips 2]

[image: Pointy Hips without the wireframe]

[image: Pointy Hips without the wireframe 2]

[image: Character]

.blend file here: [image]

Answer (score 0):

As you see if you display the face orientation, you have flipped normals, to fix that select all in *Edit* mode and recalculate the normals with a <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>:

[image]